# How can I change the icon, icon name that lays under the icon, notification name, and notification icon for an Android app?

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop, apk

I'm running Android 5.1.

I'd like to change the icon for a few apps on my device.

I'd also like to change the app name both on the desktop and on the notification window that the OS makes pop up when those apps push notifications to my device.

Lastly, I'd like to change the notification icon that appears at the very top of my screen when a notification is pushed.

How can I do this?

I think I need to take the app, somehow "unzip" it and get the APK for it, change the image files and text files that carry those pieces of data, "re-zip" it, and finally reinstall it.

Is this correct?

How do I accomplish my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Try APK Editor. Some Launcher apps (what you call desktop) like Nova let you change app icon and their label apparently. However to change notification related things, you need to modify app, which can be illegal/unethical if developer doesn't allow to customize his/her intellectual property.

Answer (score 0):

You need an apk editor. With it you can edit app,so change icons etc.,but you also need to change JSON file becaose app need to know which file it need to use. After you edit app, you need to sign it,  most app editors do it automaticly. And then install like update over app. But there is a problem. Some apps will after update return to original settings. And some will give you notice that app is edited and forbid you from using it. So all dependent on app. You did not specify your device manufacter, but if you have Samsung you can change icons of most apps in Samsung Theme app(some thems can change app icon design and notification iconand you can also  download only app icon design).

If you only want to "edit" app you need to be vety carefully to not ruin app completly. Good Luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I downloaded an APK extractor, extracted the APK I wanted, moved it over to my Linux box, and opened it up. Where do I find the icon .png, name, notification .png icon, notification name, and notification ring tone? What are the names of those files? Where are they in the APK structure?

Comment: I managed to find all of the things I needed to change in the APK. But, when I attempted to install the altered APK, I got an error. I don't think that the APK is properly signed after altering it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also change JSON file?

Comment: no. why would i need to change it? I didn't change any of the file names.

Comment: If you change any part of app(icons set), you also need to change JSON file,which control app.